# Maintain the previous state of checkbox on the page refres using angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have a checkbox, when the checkbox is checked one div is show, on the uncheck state div is hidden, it works well, but when i checked the checkbox and refresh the page it turns into unchecked state, how can I can maintain the state of checkbox on the page refresh,  Sorry for bad english, thanks in advance.

Angular code:

```
myApp.controller("expressionController", function ($scope) {
// Show or Hide Div

$scope.showHideDiv = function () {
if ($scope.chkStatus) {
$scope.showhideprop = true;
}
else {
$scope.showhideprop = false;
}
}
});
```

HTMLcode:

```
<form id="form1">
<div data-ng-app="sampleapp" data-ng-controller="expressionController">
Show or Hide Div: <input type="checkbox" name="tarn" ng-model="chkStatus" ng-change="showHideDiv()" /> <br /><br />
<div style="padding:10px; border:1px solid black; width:30%; font-weight:bold" ng-show='showhideprop'>Hi Welcome to Angularjs... Hello World</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can add `checked` to checkbox if you want have a checkbox which is checked in loaded page.. If you want to have the latest statue of checkbox you can use Cookies or session.

Answer (score 0):

you can monitor the [page before unload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) and add it to localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage for this:

```
$scope.showhideprop = localStorage.getItem('showhideprop') || false;
```

now in the function when you call `ngChange` set the current value to localStorage:

```
$scope.showHideDiv = function () {
   if ($scope.chkStatus) {
     $scope.showhideprop = true;
   } else {
     $scope.showhideprop = false;
   }
   localStorage.setItem('showhideprop', $scope.showhideprop);
}
```